# Multiplexador implementado com portas nand

Tags: álgebra-booleana

Não entendi o porquê desse circuito lógico ser um multiplexador

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um [circuito multiplexador](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexador) é caracterizado por conectar **múltiplos** fluxos de dados na entrada em somente um único na saída, de forma que seja possível "*seleciona-los*". Assim como no exemplo que você forneceu. Talvez fique mais claro se você buscar ter esse outro circuito como referência para compreender este que você está compartilhando conosco. Perceba que neste exemplo, as quatro entradas estão dispostas de forma que cada uma represente um dos possíveis estados da *tabela verdade* para uma porta lógica AND.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se você analisar com alguma atenção a imagem que nos forneceu, perceberá que ela também segue o princípio que destacamos. Note que a `Entrada S` conecta-se as portas `N2` e `N3` de formas diferentes. Perceba o que isso acarreta, analise a equação de saída de `N2` e `N3`:

A `Entrada S` sempre assume o estado inverso de uma porta para outra.

Esse circuito pode ser descrito como um Multiplexador de duas entradas. Onde a `Entrada S` é o seu seletor.